# call FormMethod.Post from javascript asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem in getting a fileupload on clicking a link on my navigation bar.

I am using mvc 4 and have a controller that loads the file in and checks it is ok, i can get this done through a input method but it doesn't look nice and want to make the UI a bit slicker so what i have is a link button called upload. what i want to do is call the FormMethod.post with the required upload details. I am very new to this so forgive me if its a simple question.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="fileUpload()">upload</a></li>
```

this works

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Authenticated", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
      <fieldset>
         Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" />
         <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </fieldset>
 }
```

Regards

Aidan

Comment: Where is `fileUpload()` defined?  Also, if your goal is to use AJAX for uploading files then be aware that some relatively recent browsers don't behave as expected for that.  AJAX form posting is universal enough, but AJAX file uploads are relatively new.  So if you have to support any older browsers it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Hi, I am unsure what browsers the end users are going to be using but we are using Chrome at the moment so if i can get it working for this and IE then think we will be covered.

Comment: What specifically is the issue you're facing?  Without seeing the implementation for `fileUpload()` we certainly can't tell if there's anything wrong there.  Are you getting an error message?  In what way is the system not behaving as expected?  For AJAX file uploads in general, a Google search will find some quick jQuery plugins to get you started.  I've used the jQuery Form plugin for this and it's worked well.

Comment: I just want to be able to send a file name off to the controller when i click open on a openFileDialog but I want to call the openFD from a link not an input button just to keep it in keeping with the rest of the form. hope this makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted, then.  If you're not looking to use AJAX, but instead are just looking to manually submit the form with JavaScript, then you can simply do something like this:  `$('form').submit();` in the JavaScript code.  (This assumes there's only one `form` element on the page.  You'd have to modify the jQuery selector if that's not the case.)

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb so to call what i have above would that be just   function form() {
            $('input[type=file]:first').trigger('click');
            $("#Authenticated").submit();
        } (sorry unsure how to do the code block.)

Comment: @David Hi i have this  `function form() {
            var x = $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
            alert(x)
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("Uploading ");
                $('form').submit();
            }
            
            } ` what happens is the alert is firing before the file is selected how can i stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work I needed to add `<input type="file" name="file" hidden="true" onchange='this.form.submit();'/>` and this allowed it to fire the item off.

Thanks for the tips @David.

Regards

Aidan